# Updating the nested dictionary under defaultdict

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, defaultdict

When attempting to update my dictionary under a nested `collection.defaultdict` Python gave me an error

Saying

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "program.py", line 18, in train_ngrams
    if graphemes[i] not in mydict[phonemes[i]].keys():
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'keys'
```

My code:

```
import csv
from collections import defaultdict

def train_ngrams(train_file):
    mydict = defaultdict(dict)
    phonemes = []
    graphemes = []
    with open(train_file, 'r') as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f) 
        next(reader)
        for p, g in reader:
            phonemes += p.split()
            graphemes += g.split()
            for i in range(len(phonemes)):
                if phonemes[i] not in mydict.keys():
                    mydict.update({phonemes[i] : graphemes[i]})
                    if graphemes[i] not in mydict[phonemes[i]].keys():
                        mydict[phonemes[i]].update({phonemes[i] : (graphemes.count(graphemes[i]) for graphemes[i] in graphemes) - 1})
                    else:
                        mydict[phonemes[i]][graphemes[i]] += 1
```

Well thing is I am trying to update the dictionary as I iterate through a csv file. And here I first want to check if it is in the `defaultdict`  already. If not then I wish to create a key and value pair.

And the value here in the `defaultdict` will actually be used later to implement a nested normal dictionary which stores some frequency stuff.

Here is an example:

```
defaultdict(<class 'dict'>, {'T': {'t': 2}, 'UH': {'oo': 1}})
```

What is a concise way to handle this error? Note that `defaultdict` is necessary in this part.

EDIT:

```
train_ngrams("training-data-ex1.csv")
```

The desired output should be

```
defaultdict(<class 'dict'>, {'T': {'t': 2}, 'UH': {'oo': 1}})
```

EDIT:

The sample txt file

```
phonemes,graphemes
T UH T,t oo t
```

Comment: `mydict[phonemes[i]]` returns a key value

Comment: What are you trying to do? With the lines `mydict.update({phonemes[i] : graphemes[i]}); if graphemes[i] not in mydict[phonemes[i]].keys():` you are basically checking `if graphemes[i] not in graphemes[i].keys():`, which does not seem to make a lot of sense.

Comment: @tobias_k I wish to check if that key and value pair exists in the defaultdict, if not then I would have to update it with that value and pair so that I can actually manipulate it and get the correct output that I desired.

Comment: @tobias_k added. Sorry about that.

Comment: @user3100115 But I need that "key value" to be a nested dictionary later on, as you can see in the lines below that I wanted to update the value to become another dictionary.

Comment: Why is `oo` not added to `T`? Should they be paired up? Are there always as many phonemes as there are graphemes?

Comment: @tobias_k Yes there always the same number of phonemes and graphemes. Also 'oo' is paired to 'UH' due to the position of that.(Meaning oo is at graphemes[1] same as 'UH' at phonemes[1])

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to pair up elements, you have to use [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#zip), not a double-for-loop.

```
mydict = collections.defaultdict(lambda: collections.defaultdict(int))
with open("training-data-ex1.csv") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    next(reader) # skip header
    for phonemes, graphemes in reader:
        for p, g in zip(phonemes.split(), graphemes.split()):
            mydict[p][g] += 1
```

This uses a `defaultdict` of `defaultdict` of `int`, so the result looks a bit weird, but it's essentially just what you wanted: `defaultdict(<function <lambda> at 0x7fd297740840>, {'T': defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {'t': 2}), 'UH': defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {'oo': 1})})`, or, without all that `defaultdict` boilerplate, `{'T': {'t': 2}, 'UH': {'oo': 1}}`.

Comment: Would zip delete the duplicates in a container first and then convert it to a dict?

Comment: No, `zip` just iterates the pairs. Instead of deleting dupes and then using count, just iterate the pairs and count +1 for each. Much simpler.

Comment: I see, I will definitely try that and see how it goes. Thank you!